# Proving that a Stochastic integral is a Martingale

Tags: martingales, local-martingales

I am trying to prove the following:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E\left(\int_{0}^{t \wedge \tau_{n}} e^{-\delta s} v(X_{s})X_{s} dW_{s}\right)=0$$

where $\tau_{n}$ is a sequence of stopping times with the property that $P(\tau_{n}\rightarrow \infty)=1$, $v(x)$ is a function with a jump discontinuity at one point and linear growth, and $X_{s}$ is a continuous process that satisfy $E(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\delta s}X_{s}^2ds)<\infty$

I think that proving the following inequality is enough

$$E\left(\int_{0}^{T} \lbrace e^{-\delta s} v(X_{s})X_{s}\rbrace^2 ds\right)<\infty$$

How can I prove this? Is the fact that $v$ is bounded in any interval and $X_{s}$ is continuous enough?

Comment: No, that is not enough.  You will need to make use of the linear growth rate, at the very least.  It's not obvious to me that this is true, though: if $v(x) = x$, then you're asking to show $E[\int_0^T (e^{\delta s} X_s^2)^2ds] < \infty$, which I don't think follows from the hypotheses.